# How to insert JS into HTML alert()?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to insert below swal() function to inside alert() onclick function?

```html
<div class="finddbbutton">
  <button class="button" onclick="alert('');">Pokaz Opis</button>
  </div>
```

```js
<script>swal("<?php echo htmlentities($row['description'], ENT_QUOTES);?>");</script>
```

EDIT:
How to display swal() functions when users click on button?
Swal() function is javascript function and i can't do that like this below,
because it doesn't work:

`<button class="button" onclick="swal("<?php echo htmlentities($row['description'], ENT_QUOTES);?>");">Pokaz Opis</button>` 

This is wrong too:
`<button class="button" onclick="<script>swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");</script>">Pokaz Opis</button>` 
Do you understand? I don't know how to display JS function swal() inside HTML DOM button onclick=""

Comment: Please clarify the question to include what you're actually are trying to do. What should happen where and when? The title makes no sense since HTML doesn't have any alerts. Both `alert()` and `swal()` are JavaScript. It's important that your question is as detailed as possible to reduce the amount of assumptions and guesses from our part.

Comment: I think he wants to put the second code into onclick="alert(' ');"

Comment: Swal and alert are both ways of making a popup message. Why would you want to put one inside the other one? It really makes no sense. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ainz - Please don't make edits with assumptions of what the OP means. _They_ need to clarify the question.

Comment: `because it doesn't work`..."doesn't work" isn't an error message or a useful problem description. What actually happens when you try that? Do you get a console error? You should mention it to us. But anyway, stop putting event handlers into your HTML markup and learn to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. Then a) your code will be easier to read and easier to maintain and debug, and b) little problems like this will probably disappear at the same time.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edit my question, fact it was stupid to insert swal inside alert, now i don't know how to write js swal inside button atribut onclick

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to stop putting event handlers into your HTML markup and learn to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Then

a) your code will be easier to read and easier to maintain and debug, and

b) little problems like this can disappear at the same time.

With this approach your requirement becomes easy to implement. Demo:

```js
document.getElementById("alertButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  swal("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<div class="finddbbutton">
  <button class="button" id="alertButton">Pokaz Opis</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, i do that as you wish, but i change swal() function this:
`swal("<?php echo htmlentities($row['description'], ENT_QUOTES);?>");`
And it is very weird, after clicking first button on page swal function is display but not to good motorcycle; still other buttons are not working;

Comment: First button display swal() but display 'description' from another motorcycle; another button doesn't display swal()

Comment: We can't really help you with that though, because you didn't show enough about the PHP for us to understand which rows it is processing, and you didn't show anything about any other buttons. I have answered the question you asked, which was how to make it show a sweetalert when the button is clicked. So you should accept the answer on that basis. If you have a more detailed question about getting the contents right, or getting it to work with other buttons, you should ask new questions about those different issues.